# Python: Calling a function based on a argument value

Tags: python, python-decorators

From my main code, I want to call a function X regardless of argument v. In the background, the function Y or Z is called based on the value of v.

For example, main code is -

```
i = X(v)
```

Now, functions Y or Z are called if v="a" or v="b".

```
def X(v):
    pass
def Y(v):
    # called if v="a"
def Z(v):
    # called if v="b"
```

I think a decorator can be used but I don't have enough knowledge about decorators.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing so? I don't think decorators are necessary. In your `X()` function, why not do `if v == 'a': Y(v)` and `elif v == 'b': Z(v)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to have `X` call `Y` or `Z`.  `X` would then be more of a dispatcher instead of a decorator, which matches what you have (calling `X` directly).  Check out @ezig's answer for the code.

`decorator`s are for changing something about a function, or its environment, or to register it -- not usually to pick different functions; although a notable exception to that is [singledispatch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/singledispatch), introduced [into Python3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

An example of singledispatch (using an older version called simplegeneric) in my own code:

```
@simplegeneric
def float(*args, **kwds):
    return __builtin__.float(*args, **kwds)


@float.register(timedelta)
def timedelta_as_float(td):
    seconds = td.seconds
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds = (seconds - hours * 3600) * (1.0 / 3600)
    return td.days * 24 + hours + seconds


@float.register(Time)
def Time_as_float(t):
    return t.tofloat()
```

and then I can call `float()` on `timedelta`s, custom `Time`s, or the normal stuff, and get a float back.

Comment: I think singledispatch is smth I may be looking for. "if-elif" is not a great choice since I have multiple functions (X,Y,Z were just examples).

Comment: @user3267989: I added an example of `singledispatch`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I think this is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with an `if` statement?

```
def X(v):
    if v == "a":
        Y(v)
    elif v == "b":
        Z(v)
```