# print depending how many arguments given

Tags: python, function

Python beginner here trying to learn by doing, here i have two functions 'main','area'.
the one which has two arguments should print     `y = math.pi *a*b` and the one which does not have two arguments should print     `x = math.pi *a**2` in my code it is currently printing like this " First (153.93804002589985, 0.0)
Second (78.53981633974483, 62.83185307179586) " (why its printing these 0.0 and 78.53981633974483?), how to make it check that if one parameter is given do this and if two do that ?

```
import math

def area(a,b=0):
     y = math.pi *a*b
     x = math.pi *a**2
     
     return x,y
  

def main():
     
     print("First", area(7))

     print("Second", area(5, 4))


main()
```

Comment: "how to make it check that if one parameter is given do this and if two do that ?" since you used a default value `b=0` the `area` function is using it as a 'normal' variable. What are your expectations from the current code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Calling a function based on a argument value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777424/python-calling-a-function-based-on-a-argument-value)

Comment: Your function `area` is using `return x,y` which returns a tuple, and you're printing the tuple so it is printed as (xvalue,yvalue). If you want just the first value use e.g. `print("First", area(7)[0])`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, exactly? Why do you want the function to work this way?

Comment: BTW, what is `b` in `math.pi *a*b`? Did you mean just `a*b` for the area of a rectangle?

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-an-Ellipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
import math

def area(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        # b not specified:
        x = math.pi * a**2
    else:
        # b specified:
        x = math.pi * a*b 
    return x
  
def main():
     print("First", area(7))
     print("Second", area(5, 4))

main()
```

Output is

```
First 153.93804002589985
Second 62.83185307179586
```

When `b` is not specified, it is set to `None`. Then you test for that in the function.

The reason it prints e.g. `(153.93804002589985, 0.0)` in your original example is that you return a tuple `(x, y)` from the function with `return x,y`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a tuple, but the caller of the functions does not know which value to use. Instead, your function should just return either one or the other value, depending on the provided inputs. Also, I would suggest using `None` as the default for `b` since `0` might be a valid value.

```
def area(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        return math.pi * a**2
    else:
        return math.pi * a * b
```

Alternatively, you could also use a ternary `... if ... else ...` for either the entire expression or just the part that is different:

```
def area(a, b=None):
    return math.pi * a * (b if b is not None else a)
```

The output will then be just

```
First 153.93804002589985
Second 62.83185307179586
```